# Empty result when using mySQL WEEK() to find dates in current week

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

We are using the following statement to select dates of birth which occur in the current week:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE WEEK(dob,1) = WEEK(CURDATE(),1) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Our 'dob' column has the type DATE and contains 1 record where dob is 1972-07-09. However, when we run our query (today is 2014-07-07) we get an empty result.

Any ideas why?? Does WEEK() only work on columns with type DATETIME?

Thanks in advance for an help!

Comment: `1972-07-09` is `YYYY-MM-DD` OR `YYYY-DD-MM`format?

Comment: @ Sadikhasan: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: What you want to do using this query just mention here.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT WEEK('1972-07-09',1);  //result= 27
SELECT WEEK('2014-07-07',1);  //result=28
```

For Example :

```
SELECT WEEK('2014-01-18',1);  //result=3
```

Your where condition does not satisfy that why It's return `false` and `Empty Result`.

Check [**Manual here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Comment: So WEEK() takes account of the year, I guess?

Comment: It will consider total number of week from first month of each year

Comment: Ok. So I need to change 1972-07-09 to 2014-07-09 to get the result I'm looking for! Can I do this in my SQL statement??

Comment: Do you know what is meaning of parameter `1` in week function?

Comment: I think it defines the start of the week as a Monday

Comment: Yes! you are right. So you have to debug your query and check it for further process.

Answer (score 0):

2014-07-07 is week 28 and 1972-07-09 is week 27. 27 is not equals 28 so you get no result.

You can check this with that query:

```
select week('2014-07-07',1),week('1972-07-09',1) from tbl_user ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT WEEK('1972-07-09',1);
```

result: 27

```
SELECT WEEK('2014-07-07',1);
```

result: 28

In this case your condition `WHERE WEEK(dob,1) = WEEK(CURDATE(),1)` is False. That's why you get an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of week is not the same as MySQLs.  For a better and more efficient result you should instead decide on the min and max range you wish to find and select that which allows you to define when your week starts and ends.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_user 
-- min range == 00:00:00 on the first day of week
WHERE dob >= ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) DAY)
-- max range == 00:00:00 on the first day of next week
AND dob < ADDDATE(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 8-DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) DAY) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The start and end date can be adjusted as needed, but because you aren't applying a function to the `dob` field you will avoid a table scan.